# joint_state_publisher zeros param

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have to set a default value in my launch file containing a joint_state_publisher. I saw in the documentation that there is a parameter "zeros" to do it but I can not figure how to use it. If I have two joints named "joint0" and "joint1" and my default value is 0.7 for both, how have I to write the launch file?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199028/joint_state_publisher-zeros-param/) by [Enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/2027/enrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/2027/enrico/) on 2014-12-09**:
If someone can point to me an example launch file I will check it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Specify the `zeros` dictionary at the **root** namespace, (I don't know why `joint_state_publisher` does not use the node's private one, but that's how it is). In yaml syntax, this should be (untested):

```
zeros:
  foo_joint: 1.0
  bar_joint: -1.0
```

If it doesn't work, ask the [source](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/indigo-devel/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher#L83).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/2027/enrico/) on 2014-12-10**:
Thx Adolfo! I'll try and let you know!